# How come the event listener I am adding only works for elements I got by Id instead of by class?

Tags: javascript, html, button, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a very simple java script quiz to try and learn the language.

```
var result = document.getElementById("result");

var rightAnswer = document.getElementById("correct").addEventListener("click",correctAnswer);

function correctAnswer(){
 result.innerText="Correct";
};

var wrongAnswer = document.getElementsByClassName("wrong").addEventListener("click",wrongAnswer);

function wrongAnswer(){
 result.innerText="Wrong";
};
```

When I run it and test the correct answer works fine but the wrong answers are unresponsive. When I look in the console it says that "document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function" which confuses me seeing how I formatted it exactly like the other line with the exception of the "getElementsByClassName". Can I not add the same event listener to multiple buttons of the same class? 
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Quiz</title>

</head>

<body>
<p>Who was the first president of the United States?</p>

<button class='button wrong' type='button'>Thomas Jefferson</button>

<button class='button' id='correct' type='button'>George Washington</button>

<button class='button wrong' type='button'>James Madison</button>

<button class='button wrong' type='button'>John F Kennedy</button>

<p id='result'></p>

<script src='quiz.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is your html code?

Comment: @Utkanos The OP read the console... Just couldn't understand what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your error console is because you can't run `addEventListener()` chained to `getElementsByTagName()`.

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a node*set*, whereas `addEventListener()` is a method of the HTML *node* object, not nodeset object.

In other words, it runs on a single node. This means we either need to iterate over the nodeset and bind the event to each node found, or use event delegation.

**Iteration approach**

```
var wrong = document.querySelectorAll(".wrong");
wrong.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click",wrongAnswer, false);
});
```

**Delegation approach**

With event delegation, you bind not to each and every node but to a common parent or ancestor. You then interrogate which node triggered the event.

We can rely on this because events "[bubble](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)"; they fire not only for the element to which they're bound, but also that element's child/descendant nodes, from the innermost outwards.

In other words, the trigger element (`evt.target`) and the context element (`this`) may not be one and the same.

Let's imagine all your `.wrong` elements live in a common container, with ID `#wrong`.

We could then do:

```
document.querySelector('#wrong').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var trigger_el = evt.target;
    if (!evt.target.matches('.wrong') return; //do nothing - was some other element
    wrongAnswer.call(trigger_el); //call wrongAnswer in the context of the trigger element
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the result of document.getElementsByClassName("wrong") in order to addEventListeners because getElement**s**ByClassName will always return multiple elements. You can do so simply:

```
var wrongAnswer = document.getElementsByClassName("wrong");
for(n = 0; n < wrongAnswer.length; n++){
  wrongAnswer[n].addEventListener("click",wrongAnswer);
}
```